# What genre are the epic musical pieces from fantasies such as Lord Of The Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I'm looking to find the genre of music that is played in Lord of the rings and other similar such movies. I often like the style which involves a string instrument like the violin or viola.

I'm not sure whether it's over a wide period of time but I've looked at medieval genres and they are not quite the same.

A lot of the compositions have an uplifting or epic feel to them that can take control of emotions and really get you into scenes. The combination of deep but slow bass drums I think is usually crucial to this.

If someone is more aware of the matter and could help out that'd be great!

Comment: A start would be [Music of the Lord of the Rings film series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings_film_series).

Comment: If you create a "Celtic" channel in Pandora internet radio, LOTR music is included in the playlist. I'd qualify it as Celtic myself. But I don't see how this is on topic. It's a question about musical style, not sci-fi or fantasy. It might be a better fit at movies.stachexchange.com

Comment: Might this be a bit better for [movies.se]?

Comment: If you scroll up in SFF chat a couple days back, I posted a really cool Youtube video of two wonderful Harp players playing the "Far over the misty mountain cold" (which appears in "Hobbit" trailer)

Comment: @Iszi: It's on-topic here, so I don't see why it should be moved, unless nobody is able to answer it for a significant amount of time.

Comment: Most classical scores for modern films fall under the symphonic category.